# Converting C to MIPS assembly with pointers

Tags: c, pointers, mips

I'm trying to store a pointer initialized as:

```
int* x;
```

into a regular variable initialized as

```
int y;
```

thus:

```
y = *x;
```

In mips is it just as simple as

```
$s1 = ($a0);?
```

And vice versa?

Comment: Neither `x` nor `y` are initialized in that example.  Do you mean 'declared'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assembly language usually doesn't have operators.  You probably want the `lw` instruction:

```
lw $s1, 0($a0)
```

The use of `$s1` and `$a0` is of course context dependent.  If those register match the rest of the code you're using, it'll be fine.

Comment: As I looked more into it I began to think that.  Thanks for confirming it though!

Comment: Thank you! Would you do the same thing if it was something like `*y = *x` except like `lw 0($s1), 0($a0)`?

Comment: @jcflinn14, no. You'd need to use two instructions, a load followed by a store.